# local language without strftime (deprecated) but with date

Tags: php, date, time, multilingual

So, i used this code before `strftime()` became deprecated:

`setlocale(LC_TIME, IT);`
`echo "<p>" . strftime("%A %e %h %Y", strtotime($value)) . "</p>";`

[image: strftime() output]

And now, using `date()` with the same code the output do not change language.

`setlocale(LC_TIME, 'it_IT.utf8');`
`echo "<p>" . date("l d M Y", strtotime($value)) . "</p>";`

[image: date() output]

**ignore variable $value

I don't see differences between `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'IT')` and `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'it_IT.utf8')` on `date()`... but `strftime()` works only with `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'IT')` and not the second one

Any ideas?

Comment: Use [`IntlDateFormatter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) instead.

Comment: [`Date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) use [`DateTimeInterface::format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) and these format **does not use locales. All output is in English.** It was documented on that page.

Comment: Thank you! i really should read with more attention the manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`date()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) use format accepted by [`DateTimeInterface::format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method.

The method `DateTimeInterface::format()` does not use locales. All output is in English.
So, this means that `date()` function also not use locales either.

Testing:

```php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'IT.utf8');
echo date('l', time()).'<br>';// display Friday

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr');
echo date('l', time()).'<br>';// display Friday

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'th');
echo date('l', time()).'<br>';// display Friday
```

All locales display the same: **Friday**.

#### `strftime()` is deprecated.

What is the replacement for display date/time with locales (and maybe including time zone)?
The [`IntlDateFormatter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) is the best option.

From your previous code:

```php
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'IT.utf8');
echo "<p>" . strftime("%A %e %h %Y", time()) . "</p>";// display venerdì 15 apr 2022
```

You can now use:

```php
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter('IT',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL
);
$fmt->setPattern('EEEE d LLL yyyy');
echo $fmt->format(time());// display venerdì 15 apr 2022
```

The format will be use `setPattern()` method and possible patterns are documented at https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/.

Comment: It is sad that we have to go from one line with `strftime()` to this.

Comment: @oelna Yeah, that's PHP. They always break things.